# Laravel unit test delay

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

Is it possible to wait in a L5 unit test. I have the following case

```
$this->visit('/')
    ->select('Customer A', 'customer')// This will fire $.getJSON and populate the 'project' select object
    //I need to wait a bit here for the 'project' select object to be populated
    ->select('Project A', 'project')
```

The select object called `customer` fires a $.getJSON on change which populates the `project` select object.

Comment: Have you tried the `sleep()` function of php?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I don't know how the phpunit test is working. but if it's done via curl the javascript code won't be executed, so your select will never fire an ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because the Ajax request is fired after the page is loaded. And it does not contain the project data from Ajax request.

You can check out the [laracasts/integrated](https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/wiki/Extras#laravel-with-selenium) from here and use Selenium driver if you want to use [waitForElement()](https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/wiki/Learn-the-API#waitforelementelement-timeout--5000)

Then you can wait for specified time period to wait for ajax requests to complete.

Comment: I no longer have the above mentioned use case, I will accept your answer.